# Flutter signing app with same key.jks not working

Tags: flutter, google-play

I developed my Flutter Android application on Windows 10 and released it internally on Google Play. Now I switched from Windows 10 to Mac and trying to update my Google Play app but getting the follwing error.

**You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint**:

[ SHA1: 11:AF:0B:9E:B5:34:92:E7:2B:3A:53:62:C1:D5:2F:4D:81:7D:9A:95 ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 00:DE:7B:1A:1E:FC:C4:5A:05:15:3C:1E:03:63:BB:34:13:0F:67:32 ]

I have used the same key.jks file to sign the app on Mac os. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print the key used to sign an apk like this:

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app.apk
```

Try this on an APK signed on Windows and an APK signed on Mac. This will tell you if you are really signing with the same keystore / key. I suspect something is going wrong with your process.

Comment: Hi I found out the issue. Instead of release I was using with debug. What you sent is also very useful. Thanks